# How to bookmark most using linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line

How i can bookmark my custom command line in linux (centos 6.2)?

I'm using `history | grep keyword` and then `!command number` now.

But is there any faster solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use alias:

```
alias lala="ls -lrt|grep a"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can define an `alias`, a function, or write a script in your `bin` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Most shell's provides more complex history expansion. For example you can use

```
!?str
```

in zsh, bash etc. to execute the most recent command that contains `str`.

Another possibility to save keystrokes would be to use the incremental search of the history if you want a broader control over what you want to select.

To search the history backwards this feature is usually bound to `<ctrl>-r`, for forward search it's `<ctrl>-s` (at least in bash and zsh).

Answer (score 0):

Just put a comment tag on it and you can search for the tag latter.

```
$ my-command # tag-bookmark-1
```

Then later you can grep or search history for tag-bookmark-1.
Use something shorter if you would like.
(I can't say about !, because I always use export histchars="")

Comment: I used this way in my question!